# CakePHP Containable error: a two level association doesn't work

Tags: cakephp, containable

I do the next query:

```
        $this->find('all',array(
            'contain' => array(
                'User' => array('id','facebook_id','name','username','Author' => array('first_name','last_name','code','photo')),
                'Tab.code'
            ),
            'fields' => array('Comment.date','Comment.time','Comment.content'),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Tab.code' => $code
            ),
            'limit' => $limit,
            'offset' => $offset
        ));
```

Comment...

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array('foreignKey' => 'user_id'),
        'Tab' => array('foreignKey' => 'tab_id')
    );
```

User...

```
    public $hasOne = array('Author' => array('foreignKey' => 'id'));
```

and Author...

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'id'
        )
    );
```

This returns something like this (in json)...

```
[
    {
        "Comment": {
            "date": "2001-12-15",
            "time": "17:32:12",
            "content": "..."
        },
        "User": {
            "id": "29",
            "facebook_id": "1234",
            "name": "User 29",
            "username": "user29"
        },
        "Tab": {
            "code": "llibre-de-prova-29",
            "id": "229"
        }
    }
    ...
]
```

...while I expect that attached to User appears an Author with the fields I specified. Do you know why Author doesn't appear? I did other contains with two levels of recursivity on the code and all works as expected.

Thank you for your help and attention!

Comment: Can you show us the relationships for Author please.

Comment: I updated the question with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your model has the Containable behavior attached. It should include the following line:

```
$actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Pay attention to make sure that you didn't omit an "s" in "acts" which is a common typo that is hard to spot. You can also attach the Containable behavior on the fly like this:

```
$this->YourModel->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
$this->YourModel->find('all', array('contain' => array(...)));
```

Also make sure you type "contain" as the array key, not "contains".

Comment: Wow, that was the problem, I forgot the 's'! Thank you.

Comment: that "s" was a life saver :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the fields in the 'fields' key. Treat it like an additional `find()` call.

```
$this->find('all', array(
            'contain' => array(
                'User' => array(
                    'fields' => array('id','facebook_id','name','username'),
                    'Author' => array(
                        'fields' => array('first_name','last_name','code','photo')
                    ),
                    'Tab.code'
                ),
            ),
            'fields' => array('Comment.date','Comment.time','Comment.content'),
            'conditions' => array(
                'Tab.code' => $code
            ),
            'limit' => $limit,
            'offset' => $offset
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->find('all',array(
        'contain' => array(
            'User' => array('id','facebook_id','name','username','Author' =>array( 'AuthorModelName'=>array('first_name','last_name','code','photo'))),
            'Tab.code'
        ),
```

Comment: I've edited so your code is formatted as code. Please edit to add some explanation of why this code is what the asker needs.

Answer (score 0):

All the foreign keys must be in your fields array

```
'fields' => array('Comment.date','Comment.time','Comment.content', 'Comment.user_id', ....)
```